# How do I create a JS script that repetitively presses a key multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am new, very, very new to JS. I don't even know the basics, but I just want help with a quick short script.

It is supposed to be a simple script that spams a key with Tampermonkey.

This is what I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match        *://diep.io/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    function f(e){
        var a = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            shiftKey: false
        });
        delete a.keyCode;
        Object.defineProperty(a, "keyCode", {
            "value": 220
        });
        dispatchEvent(a);
    }
    function a(e) {
        addEventListener(e, f);
    }

    for(var i of ["focus", "blur", "keyup"]) {
        a(i);
    }
}());
```

Instead of pressing keycode 220 down repeatedly, it holds it down. Can you fix it so that the key is "being spammed," at a fast pace?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` as for me. Look at that:

```
const mySpammer = function() {
    console.log("Spammed!");
}

setInterval(mySpammer(), 100);
```

It's a built-in JavaScript method, it also asynchronous. So, your Javascript Code won't blocked at the run-time. But ıt's not inclusive it's exclusive. First calling is, after 100ms (on my example), so you can call it yourself first time, like that:

```
mySpammer();
setInterval(mySpammer(), 100);
```

It will call when the code enters at `mySpammer()`, after 100ms setInterval works. Hopefully it works.

Comment: where do i add this part of the script in

Comment: @DavidtheGoat123 Where do you want to do. Just put your function out that is Closure Function, and store it in a variable. After that, call your function without `setInterval`. After calling it manually, you need to call it with `setInterval`. The schema of your code look like this. Try to make it. Of you can't, im here, try to examine my example.